# Template structure

Tags: loop, templates

Question regarding template structure:

In a custom loop, I inserted a get_template_part('resources', 'layout') which contains the following markup:

```
<div class="custom-content">
    <?php if ( get_post_type() === 'videos' ) { ?>
        <div class="video-popup">
            <?php the_field('video_popup'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="featured-image">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
            <?php if ( get_post_type() === 'articles' ) { ?>
                <p class="custom-content-btn">
                    <a href="<?php the_field( 'article_link' )?>" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank"><?php echo __('READ'); ?></a>
                </p>
            <?php } ?> 
        </div>
        <?php if ( get_post_type() === 'audio' ) { ?>
        <div class="audio-content">
            <?php the_field('audio_clip'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I have 3 CPT (videos, audio and articles). However I'm not sure if this is the best way to conditionally display the contents; seems a bit messy. I guess the tricky part is that there's some markup that appears for all CPT, that's sitting inbetween those conditional markups.

What would be considered the 'best practice' to tackle this? Appreciate any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you're in a custom loop that returns various post_types:

```
//.....
 while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
   get_template_part($post->post_type,'layout');
endwhile;
```

in this way you don't use extra conditionals and relying on get_template_part() you simply need different files `post_type1-layout.php` , `post_type2-layout.php`, etc.. in the root folder of your theme / child theme keeping the templates separate, cleaner and more usable.

Also you can put the template files in a subfolder `customTemplates` and use

```
get_template_part('customTemplates/'.$post->post_type,'layout');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no best practice, but if you take a look at the Wordpress default themes, they would load a different template part based on the custom post type, so the `if( get_post_type() === 'videos' )` etc... would be placed in the file where your loop is, and load a different partial depending on that.

Comment: Thansk for this!